# Extracting unsigned char from array of numpy.uint8

Tags: python, c++, numpy, boost-python

I have code to extract a numeric value from a python sequence, and it works well in most cases, but not for a numpy array.

When I try to extract an unsigned char, I do the following

```
unsigned char val = boost::python::extract<unsigned char>(sequence[n]);
```

where sequence is any python sequence and n is the index.
 I get the following error:

```
TypeError: No registered converter was able to produce a C++ rvalue of type 
unsigned char from this Python object of type numpy.uint8
```

How can I successfully extract an unsigned char in C++? Do I have to write/register special converters for numpy types? I would rather use the same code that I use for other python sequences, and not have to write special code that uses the `PyArrayObject*`.

Comment: Numpy uses native c types, so your goal is not going to be to convert the value but to just use it directly (by figuring out what it's memory location is, for instance).

Comment: sequence is a boost::python::object, should I use static_cast instead? Like `unsigned char val = static_cast<unsigned char>(sequence[n]);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One can register a custom from-python converter with Boost.Python that handles conversions from NumPy array scalars, such as `numpy.uint8`, to C++ scalars, such as `unsigned char`.  A custom from-python converter registration has three parts:

- A function that checks if a `PyObject` is convertible. A return of `NULL` indicates that the `PyObject` cannot use the registered converter.
- A construct function that constructs the C++ type from a `PyObject`. This function will only be called if `converter(PyObject)` does not return `NULL`.
- The C++ type that will be constructed.

Extracting the value from the NumPy array scalar requires a few NumPy C API calls:

- [`import_array()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/c-api.array.html#import_array) must be called within the initialization of an extension module that is going to use the NumPy C API.  Depending on how the extension(s) are using the NumPy C API, other requirements for importing may need to occur.
- [`PyArray_CheckScalar()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/c-api.array.html#PyArray_CheckScalar) checks if a `PyObject` is a NumPy array scalar.
- [`PyArray_DescrFromScalar()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/c-api.array.html#PyArray_DescrFromScalar) gets the [data-type-descriptor](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/c-api.types-and-structures.html#PyArray_Descr) object for an array scalar.  The data-type-descriptor object contains information about how to interpret the underlying bytes.  For example, its [`type_num`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/c-api.types-and-structures.html#PyArray_Descr.type_num) data member contains an [enum value](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/c-api.dtype.html#enumerated-types) that corresponds to a C-type.
- [`PyArray_ScalarAsCtype()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/c-api.array.html#PyArray_ScalarAsCtype) can be used to extract the C-type value from a NumPy array scalar.

---

Here is a complete example demonstrating using a helper class, `enable_numpy_scalar_converter`, to register specific NumPy array scalars to their corresponding C++ types.

```cpp
#include <boost/cstdint.hpp>
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#define NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION
#include <numpy/arrayobject.h>

// Mockup functions.

/// @brief Mockup function that will explicitly extract a uint8_t
///        from the Boost.Python object.
boost::uint8_t test_generic_uint8(boost::python::object object)
{
  return boost::python::extract<boost::uint8_t>(object)();
}

/// @brief Mockup function that uses automatic conversions for uint8_t.
boost::uint8_t test_specific_uint8(boost::uint8_t value) { return value; }

/// @brief Mokcup function that uses automatic conversions for int32_t.
boost::int32_t test_specific_int32(boost::int32_t value) { return value; }


/// @brief Converter type that enables automatic conversions between NumPy
///        scalars and C++ types.
template <typename T, NPY_TYPES NumPyScalarType>
struct enable_numpy_scalar_converter
{
  enable_numpy_scalar_converter()
  {
    // Required NumPy call in order to use the NumPy C API within another
    // extension module.
    import_array();

    boost::python::converter::registry::push_back(
      &convertible,
      &construct,
      boost::python::type_id<T>());
  }

  static void* convertible(PyObject* object)
  {
    // The object is convertible if all of the following are true:
    // - is a valid object.
    // - is a numpy array scalar.
    // - its descriptor type matches the type for this converter.
    return (
      object &&                                                    // Valid
      PyArray_CheckScalar(object) &&                               // Scalar
      PyArray_DescrFromScalar(object)->type_num == NumPyScalarType // Match
    )
      ? object // The Python object can be converted.
      : NULL;
  }

  static void construct(
    PyObject* object,
    boost::python::converter::rvalue_from_python_stage1_data* data)
  {
    // Obtain a handle to the memory block that the converter has allocated
    // for the C++ type.
    namespace python = boost::python;
    typedef python::converter::rvalue_from_python_storage<T> storage_type;
    void* storage = reinterpret_cast<storage_type*>(data)->storage.bytes;

    // Extract the array scalar type directly into the storage.
    PyArray_ScalarAsCtype(object, storage);

    // Set convertible to indicate success. 
    data->convertible = storage;
  }
};

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(example)
{
  namespace python = boost::python;

  // Enable numpy scalar conversions.
  enable_numpy_scalar_converter<boost::uint8_t, NPY_UBYTE>();
  enable_numpy_scalar_converter<boost::int32_t, NPY_INT>();

  // Expose test functions.
  python::def("test_generic_uint8",  &test_generic_uint8);
  python::def("test_specific_uint8", &test_specific_uint8);
  python::def("test_specific_int32", &test_specific_int32);
}
```

Interactive usage:

```python
>>> import numpy
>>> import example
>>> assert(42 == example.test_generic_uint8(42))
>>> assert(42 == example.test_generic_uint8(numpy.uint8(42)))
>>> assert(42 == example.test_specific_uint8(42))
>>> assert(42 == example.test_specific_uint8(numpy.uint8(42)))
>>> assert(42 == example.test_specific_int32(numpy.int32(42)))
>>> example.test_specific_int32(numpy.int8(42))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
Boost.Python.ArgumentError: Python argument types in
    example.test_specific_int32(numpy.int8)
did not match C++ signature:
    test_specific_int32(int)
>>> example.test_generic_uint8(numpy.int8(42))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: No registered converter was able to produce a C++ rvalue of type
  unsigned char from this Python object of type numpy.int8
```

A few things to note from the interactive usage:

- Boost.Python was able to extract `boost::uint8_t` from both `numpy.uint8` and `int` Python objects.
- The `enable_numpy_scalar_converter` does not support promotions.  For instance, it should be safe for `test_specific_int32()` to accept a `numpy.int8` object that is promoted to a larger scalar type, such as `int`.  If one wishes to perform promotions:

  - `convertible()` will need to check for compatible `NPY_TYPES`
  - `construct()` should use [`PyArray_CastScalarToCtype()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/c-api.array.html#PyArray_ScalarAsCtype) to cast the extracted array scalar value to the desired C++ type.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a slightly more generic version of the accepted answer:
https://github.com/stuarteberg/printnum

(The converter is copied from the [VIGRA](https://github.com/ukoethe/vigra) C++/Python bindings.)

The accepted answer points out that it does not support casting between scalar types. This converter *will* allow implicit conversion between any two scalar types (even, say, `int32` to `int8`, or `float32` to `uint8`).  I think that's generally nicer, but there is a slight convenience/safety trade-off made here.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/python.hpp>

#define NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION

// http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/c-api.array.html#importing-the-api
#define PY_ARRAY_UNIQUE_SYMBOL printnum_cpp_module_PyArray_API
#include <numpy/arrayobject.h>
#include <numpy/arrayscalars.h>


/*
 * Boost python converter for numpy scalars, e.g. numpy.uint32(123).
 * Enables automatic conversion from numpy.intXX, floatXX
 * in python to C++ char, short, int, float, etc.
 * When casting from float to int (or wide int to narrow int),
 * normal C++ casting rules apply.
 *
 * Like all boost::python converters, this enables automatic conversion for function args
 * exposed via boost::python::def(), as well as values converted via boost::python::extract<>().
 *
 * Copied from the VIGRA C++ library source code (MIT license).
 * http://ukoethe.github.io/vigra
 * https://github.com/ukoethe/vigra
 */
template <typename ScalarType>
struct NumpyScalarConverter
{
    NumpyScalarConverter()
    {
        using namespace boost::python;
        converter::registry::push_back( &convertible, &construct, type_id<ScalarType>());
    }

    // Determine if obj_ptr is a supported numpy.number
    static void* convertible(PyObject* obj_ptr)
    {
        if (PyArray_IsScalar(obj_ptr, Float32) ||
            PyArray_IsScalar(obj_ptr, Float64) ||
            PyArray_IsScalar(obj_ptr, Int8)    ||
            PyArray_IsScalar(obj_ptr, Int16)   ||
            PyArray_IsScalar(obj_ptr, Int32)   ||
            PyArray_IsScalar(obj_ptr, Int64)   ||
            PyArray_IsScalar(obj_ptr, UInt8)   ||
            PyArray_IsScalar(obj_ptr, UInt16)  ||
            PyArray_IsScalar(obj_ptr, UInt32)  ||
            PyArray_IsScalar(obj_ptr, UInt64))
        {
            return obj_ptr;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    static void construct( PyObject* obj_ptr, boost::python::converter::rvalue_from_python_stage1_data* data)
    {
        using namespace boost::python;

        // Grab pointer to memory into which to construct the C++ scalar
        void* storage = ((converter::rvalue_from_python_storage<ScalarType>*) data)->storage.bytes;

        // in-place construct the new scalar value
        ScalarType * scalar = new (storage) ScalarType;

        if (PyArray_IsScalar(obj_ptr, Float32))
            (*scalar) = PyArrayScalar_VAL(obj_ptr, Float32);
        else if (PyArray_IsScalar(obj_ptr, Float64))
            (*scalar) = PyArrayScalar_VAL(obj_ptr, Float64);
        else if (PyArray_IsScalar(obj_ptr, Int8))
            (*scalar) = PyArrayScalar_VAL(obj_ptr, Int8);
        else if (PyArray_IsScalar(obj_ptr, Int16))
            (*scalar) = PyArrayScalar_VAL(obj_ptr, Int16);
        else if (PyArray_IsScalar(obj_ptr, Int32))
            (*scalar) = PyArrayScalar_VAL(obj_ptr, Int32);
        else if (PyArray_IsScalar(obj_ptr, Int64))
            (*scalar) = PyArrayScalar_VAL(obj_ptr, Int64);
        else if (PyArray_IsScalar(obj_ptr, UInt8))
            (*scalar) = PyArrayScalar_VAL(obj_ptr, UInt8);
        else if (PyArray_IsScalar(obj_ptr, UInt16))
            (*scalar) = PyArrayScalar_VAL(obj_ptr, UInt16);
        else if (PyArray_IsScalar(obj_ptr, UInt32))
            (*scalar) = PyArrayScalar_VAL(obj_ptr, UInt32);
        else if (PyArray_IsScalar(obj_ptr, UInt64))
            (*scalar) = PyArrayScalar_VAL(obj_ptr, UInt64);

        // Stash the memory chunk pointer for later use by boost.python
        data->convertible = storage;
    }
};

/*
 * A silly function to test scalar conversion.
 * The first arg tests automatic function argument conversion.
 * The second arg is used to demonstrate explicit conversion via boost::python::extract<>()
 */
void print_number( uint32_t number, boost::python::object other_number )
{
    using namespace boost::python;
    std::cout << "The number is: " << number << std::endl;
    std::cout << "The other number is: " << extract<int16_t>(other_number) << std::endl;
}

/*
 * Instantiate the python extension module 'printnum'.
 *
 * Example Python usage:
 *
 *     import numpy as np
 *     from printnum import print_number
 *     print_number( np.uint8(123), np.int64(-456) )
 *
 *     ## That prints the following:
 *     # The number is: 123
 *     # The other number is: -456
 */
BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(printnum)
{
    using namespace boost::python;

    // http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/c-api.array.html#importing-the-api
    import_array();

    // Register conversion for all scalar types.
    NumpyScalarConverter<signed char>();
    NumpyScalarConverter<short>();
    NumpyScalarConverter<int>();
    NumpyScalarConverter<long>();
    NumpyScalarConverter<long long>();
    NumpyScalarConverter<unsigned char>();
    NumpyScalarConverter<unsigned short>();
    NumpyScalarConverter<unsigned int>();
    NumpyScalarConverter<unsigned long>();
    NumpyScalarConverter<unsigned long long>();
    NumpyScalarConverter<float>();
    NumpyScalarConverter<double>();

    // Expose our C++ function as a python function.
    def("print_number", &print_number, (arg("number"), arg("other_number")));
}
```