# Use numpy-array of dtype uint8 with boost python.h

Tags: python, c++, numpy, boost

I am trying to calculate the difference of two numpy arrays in C++ using boost/python.h.

My c-code looks similar to:

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include "boost/python/extract.hpp"
#include "boost/python/numeric.hpp"

using namespace boost::python;

void setArray(boost::python::numeric::array structure,
    boost::python::numeric::array bct,
    int size_x, int size_y,
    boost::python::numeric::array data1, boost::python::numeric::array data2,
    int data1_div, int data2_div, int neutral) {

  for (int ix = 0; ix < size_x; ix++) {
      for (int iy = 0; iy < size_y; iy++) {
        boost::uint8_t d1 = extract<boost::uint8_t>(data1[iy][ix]);
        boost::uint8_t d2 = extract<boost::uint8_t>(data2[iy][ix]);
        boost::uint8_t x = d2/data1_div + neutral - d1/data2_div;
        bct[x] += 1;
        structure[iy][ix] = x;
      }
  }
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(img_diff) {
  boost::python::numeric::array::set_module_and_type("numpy", "ndarray");
  def("setArray", &setArray);
}
```

An example how to use this from python is:

```
import numpy as np
import img_diff

h_stripe = 3
l_stripe = 7

data1_div = 17
data2_div = 17
neutral = 16

data1 = np.array(np.random.randint(0, 16, (h_stripe, l_stripe))*data1_div, dtype=np.int)
data2 = np.array(np.random.randint(0, 16, (h_stripe, l_stripe))*data2_div, dtype=np.int)

structure = np.zeros((h_stripe, l_stripe), np.uint8)
bct = np.zeros((32, ), np.uint)

img_diff.setArray(structure, bct, l_stripe, h_stripe, data1, data2, data1_div, data2_div, neutral)
```

This works fine, as long as the dtype for data1 and data2 is numpy.int. However, due to memory issues, I have to use numpy.uint8. Using uint8, I get the error

```
TypeError: No registered converter was able to produce a C++ rvalue of type unsigned char from this Python object of type numpy.uint8
```

Can anyone explain why it works with int but not with uint8? Also, why is it ok to use uint8 for structure?

Is there a good way, how to solve this?

Comment: Would [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26595350/extracting-unsigned-char-from-array-of-numpy-uint8) be of any help?

Comment: It does help with the error, thanks. However, I now realized that the for-loop gets really really slow because of the extract. So I have to find another way. Does anyone know how to access the elements of data1 and data2 directly with a pointer (withou first copying them)?